# offset a line/vector parallel to given lines

Tags: python, algorithm, math, vector, computational-geometry

Given some XY coordinates, I am attempting to create new lines which are parallel to the original coordinates.

However, they seem to be intersecting when the vector 'goes back', like this:

(**BLUE**: Original coords, **ORANGE**: programmed coords supposed to be parallel)
[image]

This is the full python code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xN = [11.86478, 24.851482, 75.38245, 84.50359, 58.3, 58.001]
yN = [4.3048816, 3.541581, 4.0219164, 2.854434, 0.0, 0.001]

newX = []
newY = []

d = 1
for i in range(len(xN)-1):
    r = np.sqrt((xN[i+1]-xN[i])**2+(yN[i+1]-yN[i])**2) 
    dx = d/r*(yN[i]-yN[i+1]) 
    dy = d/r*(xN[i+1]-xN[i]) 

    newX.append(xN[i]+dx)
    newY.append(yN[i]+dy)

plt.plot(xN, yN)
plt.plot(newX, newY)
plt.show()
```

Is there some algorithm/technique to achieve a parallel offset without intersecting with the original lines? Thanks

**UPDATE:**

While adding the `abs()` to dx/dy `d/r*abs(yN[i]-yN[i+1])` solves the first part, if I wanted to go all the way round, it still intersects, due the line being same size.

[image]

I am trying to achieve the following (I manually created the parallel line for visual understanding):
[image]

Comment: Do you expect the ORANGE line to have the same length as the BLUE line? You should try to include an example of what you want *it* to be - a hand drawn image is fine.  Seems more like a maths question than a programming question.

Comment: Just updated, the vector where to 'goes back' seems like it should be bigger, so intersection doesn't occur.

Comment: You should try to include an example of what you want it to be - a hand drawn image is fine.

Comment: Alright, the last image (3rd image)  i added, is what I am aiming to achieve

Comment: Also google "miter limit"

Comment: Yes, I will have at this. I will use @GrimTrigger suggestion with interpolation.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer if it does not give you the desired result ?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. I found the solution and made it the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found a solution which offsets the lines by chosen offset value.

This was taken from this [C# algorithm](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/01/enlarge-a-polygon-in-c/) and coded into Python.
[image]

**NOTE:** This does not work properly with collinear shape. Additionally, this is done with explicit coding, it requires refining.

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xN = [11.86478, 24.851482, 75.38245, 84.50359, 58.3, 0.4]
yN = [4.3048816, 3.541581, 4.0219164, 2.854434, 0.0, 1.0]

newX = []
newY = []

def findIntesection(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, p3x,p3y, p4x, p4y):
    dx12 = p2x - p1x
    dy12 = p2y - p1y
    dx34 = p4x - p3x
    dy34 = p4y - p3y

    denominator = (dy12*dx34-dx12*dy34)

    t1 = ((p1x - p3x) * dy34 + (p3y - p1y) * dx34)/ denominator

    t2 = ((p3x - p1x) * dy12 + (p1y - p3y) * dx12)/ -denominator;
    
    intersectX = p1x + dx12 * t1
    intersectY = p1y + dy12 * t1

    if (t1 < 0): t1 = 0
    elif (t1 > 1): t1 = 1
    if (t2 < 0): t2 = 0
    elif (t2 > 1): t2 = 1
    
    return intersectX,intersectY

def normalizeVec(x,y):
    distance = np.sqrt(x*x+y*y)
    return x/distance, y/distance

def getEnlarged(oldX, oldY, offset):
    num_points = len(oldX)
    
    for j in range(num_points):
        i = j - 1
        if i < 0:
            i += num_points
        k = (j + 1) % num_points

        vec1X =  oldX[j] - oldX[i]
        vec1Y =  oldY[j] - oldY[i]
        v1normX, v1normY = normalizeVec(vec1X,vec1Y)
        v1normX *= offset
        v1normY *= offset
        n1X = -v1normY
        n1Y = v1normX
        pij1X = oldX[i] + n1X
        pij1Y = oldY[i] + n1Y
        pij2X = oldX[j] + n1X
        pij2Y = oldY[j] + n1Y

        vec2X =  oldX[k] - oldX[j]
        vec2Y =  oldY[k] - oldY[j]
        v2normX, v2normY = normalizeVec(vec2X,vec2Y)
        v2normX *= offset
        v2normY *= offset
        n2X = -v2normY
        n2Y = v2normX
        pjk1X = oldX[j] + n2X
        pjk1Y = oldY[j] + n2Y
        pjk2X = oldX[k] + n2X
        pjk2Y = oldY[k] + n2Y
        
        intersectX,intersetY = findIntesection(pij1X,pij1Y,pij2X,pij2Y,pjk1X,pjk1Y,pjk2X,pjk2Y)
        
        #print(intersectX,intersetY)
        
        newX.append(intersectX)
        newY.append(intersetY)

getEnlarged(xN, yN, 1)

plt.plot(xN, yN)
plt.plot(newX, newY)
plt.show()
```

This gives the following output:
[image]

Comment: i have passed x [187, 879, 722, 322]

y [341, 344, 112, 112] , values with offset 20 ....it is making desired result but it is not making closed shape , i want this to be a closed shape any help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the absolute, like so

```
dx = d/r*abs(yN[i]-yN[i+1])
dy = d/r*abs(xN[i+1]-xN[i])
```

which gives

[image]

Were you looking for this result?

**EDIT**:

I have looked at this again, quite interesting. To extend on one side only you would need to consider a "handedness" of the line as you go along it. I have thought of it as a differential-geometric curve, with the tangent vector **t** (dx, dy) and its normal **n** (dy, -dx) (you have used that in your code) spanning the third vector, I think its called the binormal vector **b=t x n**. As you only want to expand the line on one side, you will have to consider the behaviour of **b**: Does it "flip", i.e., does the curve change direction? I have added this to the code (not nicely done, might need polishing but shows the point, `s3` is the z-component of **b** as I only check for "flips", have also added points for illustration):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xN = [11.86478, 24.851482, 75.38245, 84.50359, 58.3, 0.4]
yN = [4.3048816, 3.541581, 4.0219164, 2.854434, 0.0, 1.0]

newX = []
newY = []

d = 1
dx = 1
dy = 1
s3 = dx*dx + dy*dy
    
for i in range(len(xN)-1):
    if s3 < 0:
        newX.append(xN[i]+dy)
        newY.append(yN[i]-dx)
    else:
        newX.append(xN[i]-dy)
        newY.append(yN[i]+dx)
        
    r = np.sqrt((xN[i+1]-xN[i])**2+(yN[i+1]-yN[i])**2) 
    dy = d/r*(yN[i+1]-yN[i])
    dx = d/r*(xN[i+1]-xN[i])
    
    s3 = dx*dx + dy*dy # this is the cross product, z-component

if s3 < 0:
    newX.append(xN[i+1]+dy)
    newY.append(yN[i+1]-dx)
else:
    newX.append(xN[i+1]-dy)
    newY.append(yN[i+1]+dx)

plt.plot(xN, yN)
#plt.plot(newX, newY)
plt.plot(newX, newY, 'o')
plt.show()
```

which results in

[image]

All points are now on one side of the curve. This is still not ideal as - if you draw lines between the points - the outside line cuts the original line. This comes from the needed lengthening of the outside curve, which is still not considered. I think you can solve this by interpolating more points around sharp turns on the original curve.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. This seems to work for top, but if i wanted to go all the way round, it doesn't work as shown question image. But thanks for first part!

Comment: Thanks for the update, this makes sense, I think this will work with interpolation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad I could help! Time permits I will recheck, should I find more I ll post it here. Good luck!

Comment: I now found the solution, which uses a different approach.

Comment: very good! Yes, this seems to work much better!